# Авторизация через linkedin на landing page

Tags: oauth, linkedin

Добрый день.

Нужно сделать авторизацию через linkedin на landing page, что бы в дальнейшем можно было подставить данные пользователя (Имя, Фамилия, email и по возможности телефон) в поля формы.

Кто сталкивался с подобной задачей и имеет пример кода?

Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Насколько я понял, вам нужен [LinkedIn API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin?u=0) для авторизации.

Comment: Все верно.
Нет опыта, хочется пример какой-то по коду.
Возможно получится переделать))

Answer (score 2):

Вообще говоря, задача авторизации пользователем клиенту защищённых ресурсов через OAuth 2.0 не слишком тривиальна и вряд ли столь необходима на простом landing page.

Я знаком с методами работы с OAuth в java и, так как вы не указали требуемый инструментарий, пример реализации авторизации OAuth приведу именно на нём.

Для авторизации вам потребуется клиент, реализующий Authorization Code Flow (более подробно о нём смотрите RFC6749) Для приложений на java это будет Spring Security OAuth или Apache Oltu. Для приложений на других языках вы можете найти подходящий клиент [здесь](http://oauth.net/2/). После этого в соответствии с Authorization Code Flow вы должны будете получить авторизацию пользователя на доступ к его ресурсу (здесь необходимо указать необходимые scope, в данном случае это будет r_fullprofile). После этого вы получите Auth code, обменяете его на токен доступа, и запросите точку people (она есть в документации, на ссылку репутации не хватает:)). Оттуда вам уже и придёт пользовательская информация.

Пример схожего взаимодействия с Google+ можно найти здесь: [OAuth_QrealWeb](https://github.com/TanVD/OAuth_QReal-Web/tree/master/Server/src/main/java/com/resources/auth)

Указанный проект довольно большой, вам будет интересен OAuth2Config package.

В комментариях уже указали ссылку на LinkedIn API, там вы найдёте всю необходимую информацию о точках доступа и способах подключения.

Для того чтобы предоставить более полный ответ, необходимо знать хотя бы используемый инструментарий.